# JavaScript insertBefore not updating - needs double or treble click

Tags: javascript

This is driving me nuts, a simple script to swap two nodes in a two node ul:

```
// Html
<input type="button" onclick="swapItems()" value="Swap Items" />

//JavaScript
function swapItems() {
    var ul2 = document.getElementById("ul2");
    var first = ul2.firstChild;
    var last = ul2.lastChild;
    ul2.insertBefore(last, first);
}
```

It works but I have to either double click or triple click the button to see the changed list.

Comment: You mind sharing the HTML too?

Comment: The Html is pretty straightforward:
    This is another unordered list. Click buttons to swap items.
    <ul id="ul2">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" onclick="swapItems()" value="Swap Items" />
I didn’t realise that this was adding in extra blank elements but I see that now when I look at the JavaScript in developer mode, ul2 has 2 children but the nodelist has 5 nodes - #text/Item 1/#text/Item 2/#text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the childNodes of ul2 it will become apparent. The first child of ul2 is a blank text node, so is the last child. The reason you have to click a few times is that you are moving blank text nodes around. You can't see it on the web page, but if you use a web inspector you should be able to pick it up.

You could change the code to:

```
function swapItems() {
    var ul2 = document.getElementById("ul2");
    var liChildren = ul2.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var first = ul2.liChildren[0];
    var last = ul2.liChildren[liChildren.length - 1];
    ul2.insertBefore(last, first);
}
```

That should work as you wanted.

Comment: Or `lastElementChild` and `firstElementChild` if you do not care about IE<9.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespaces in #ul2. Whitespaces are also considered as children nodes.